# Specific static IP settings on different WiFi

Tags: networking, router, ip

I've been trying to set a static IP address for myself. My router details are as following:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4c77:ef95:76:961b%13
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.16
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

I set the static IP address to `192.168.1.50`. However, since I go to school and connect to my own access point I set up there, the IP it gives me is `172.168.1.2` (without a static IP). My question is, can I configure my Wifi adapter to set a static IP address *only* if I'm connected to my home network?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am assuming you're on Windows. If not then please correct. If you go into:

Network and Sharing Centre > Right click Wireless adapter > Properties > Select IPv4 > Properties.

In there configure your primary network settings under the general tab (probably obtain IP automatically) and under Alternative specify the information related to your other network.

Hope this helps

EDIT: So using alternative IP. Generally speaking you would configure your alternative configuration to specify settings when a DHCP server is not present (and cannot collect an IP automatically). If this is the case for you then set the primary to collect an IP automatically (for your school network) and assign manual configuration to alternative when at home.

If, however, this doesn't work you can probably assign both networks manually, but this would depend how your school network runs. I assume you won't be able to specify a manual connection if there are several hundred systems on the network. Be aware though, as pointed out below, once you start specifying static network configurations you won't be able to use your system anywhere else without resetting the network.

Comment: +1 for using the alternative connection settings. One would think that the saved connection setting could be edited to fix the ip address for a particular connection, but nope, the ip address is set at the "adapter" level. :(

Comment: How do you use the alternative connection settings?

Comment: @gnp | It would be nice, but they never make it that easy for us. Everything is trial and error till someone figures out how to break it... fun times.

Comment: +1 And in case the "Alternate configuration" tab is not there, you should *first* set the IP to automatic for it to appear.

Answer (score 3):

my personal tool for this issue:

https://github.com/xzer/wlanprofilemanager

it allows you to define static ip or dhcp on different SSID, and to be configured automatically.

Comment: Can you edit your answer and provide more information not just a link?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your router/ap if it supports this for not, but you should be able to [DHCP reservation](http://lifehacker.com/5822605/how-to-set-up-dhcp-reservations-so-you-never-have-to-check-an-ip-address-again) using the MAC address for your wireless card and assigning it an IP (192.168.1.50 in this case).

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you mean.

If you mean, can I set myself up with a static IP at all? The answer is yes, always.

If what you mean is: can I set up myself to have always the same IP address, the answer is no: the reason is that you will have different subnets in different places. You have 192.168.1.0/24 at home, but 172.168.1.0/24 at school. Next time you go to an Internet cafè, you may find a subnet 192.168.0.0/24, or 10.10.0.0, and so on. Having the **same** IP address on these different subnets makes it impossible to use them, since the number you chose for yourself, 192.168.1.50, belongs to your home subnet but does not belong to any other subnet mentioned above.

This is the reason why most people do not use static IPs on wifi; the most common use for static IPs is in devices which cannot be moved, so they belong by definition always to the same network: dekstops, servers, routers, printers, TVs, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to have static IP on one SSID but not others. The basic idea is that you create a Windows Task Manager task to run when you connect to a new network, which then runs a batch file that checks which SSID you've connected to. If it detects the special SSID it sets static IP and otherwise it sets dynamic IP.

If you have more than one SSID with different static IP settings, you can generalize this.

Detailed instructions:

1. Create **wlanconnect.bat** in **\users\YourUserName** with the following contents:
   `netsh wlan show interfaces | findstr /R /C:"SSID *: SPECIALSSID$" 
   if errorlevel 1 goto notAtHome
   netsh interface ip show address "Wi-Fi" | findstr /R /C:"DHCP enabled: *No"
   if not errorlevel 1 goto end
   netsh interface ip set address "Wi-Fi" static 192.168.1.223 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1
   rem netsh interface ip set dns "Wi-Fi" static 8.8.8.8
   goto end
   :notAtHome
   netsh interface ip show address "Wi-Fi" | findstr /R /C:"DHCP enabled: *Yes"
   if not errorlevel 1 goto end
   netsh interface ip set address "Wi-Fi" dhcp 
   rem netsh interface interface ip set dns "Wi-Fi" dhcp
   :end`

   Here, replace `SPECIALSSID` with the SSID you want the static IP for, and replace `192.168.1.223 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1` with your static IP, your subnet mask and your gateway. I have my DNS set to 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4 for all connections. If you want to have static DNS settings just for your special SSID, remove the `rem` before the two `netsh ... dns` commands.
2. Start Task Manager (win-R, `taskschd.msc`, enter)
3. Click on **Create Task**
4. Under **Name** put: **Toggle Static IP**
5. Click **Change User or Group**, type in **SYSTEM**, and click **OK**
6. Switch to **Conditions** tab and uncheck **Start the task only if computer is on AC power**
7. Switch to **Triggers** tab and click on **New...**
8. Under **Begin the task** choose **On an event**
9. Under **Log** choose **Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational**
10. Under **Source** choose **NetworkProfile**
11. Under **Event ID** put **10000**
12. Click **OK**
13. Switch to **Actions** tab and click on **New...**
14. Under **Program/script** browse to your **\users\YourUserName\wlanconnect.bat** file
15. Press **OK** and **OK** again. You will be prompted for your password.

Answer (score 0):

Download this freeware:
http://www.netsetman.com/en/freeware

Set your ip config in different profiles and add required conditions in 'AutoSwitch' to switch configurations automatically.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue when working on Office network which is set to static IP while the home WiFi is set to DHCP. The simplest solution I found was to set the same network setting at my Home to what the Office uses. Now I don't have to change connection settings.