# How to set up different IP settings on different WiFi networks?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop, router, ip

On my Windows 8.1 laptop I often play multiplayer games that require some port forwarding. I constantly have to change the port forwarding settings, because my IP address keeps changing every time. Is there a solution that will solve this problem for me, so I don't have to worry about it anymore?

I tried changing my IP settings to static, but it gave me problems when using my laptop on other WiFi networks, which I do a lot. Can I have different IP settings on different WiFi networks?

Comment: A similar question http://superuser.com/questions/708649/specific-static-ip-settings-on-different-wifi/708654#708654" might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if your router can link the portforwarding to MAC.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know that was a thing, and fortunately, my router at home can do that.